# i need to print the value but im getting an output as number times

Tags: python

i need to print the currency conversion. but instead of multiplying the value into 100. im gettinbg an output as the amount is repeated for 100 times

```
def curconv(curr,amount):
    value = 0
    c = ['AUD','CHF','CNY','DKK','EUR','GBP','HKD','INR','JPY','MXN','MYR','NOK','NZD','PHP','SEK','SGD','THB']
    cv = ['1.0345157','1.0237414','0.1550176','0.1651442','1.2296544','1.5550989','0.1270207','0.0177643','0.01241401','0.0751848','0.3145411','0.1677063','0.8003591','0.0233234','0.148269','0.788871','0.0313789']
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if c[i]== curr:
            value = (amount * cv[i])
    return value
print(curconv('INR',100))
```

Comment: Yes, you're multiplying strings. Use numbers.

Comment: Also, consider using a `dict` instead of two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The immediate problem is that the values in the `cv` list are `str`, but they should be `float`. The easiest (in terms of code changes) fix would be to convert the value to `float` before adding, i.e. `value = (amount * float(cv[i]))`, or better, remove all the `'` in the `cv` list.

```
def curconv(curr,amount):
    value = 0
    c = ['AUD','CHF','CNY', ...]
    cv = [1.0345157,1.0237414,0.1550176, ...]
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if c[i]== curr:
            value = (amount * cv[i])
    return value
```

Also, note that your code may behave unexpectedly if you pass an unknown currency code; better raise an exception in that case. And using a `dict` instead of two lists will make the code faster and easier to maintain. (You can create that `dict` with `dict(zip(c, cv))`.)

```
RATES = {'AUD': 1.0345157, 'CHF': 1.0237414, 'CNY': 0.1550176,
         'DKK': 0.1651442, 'EUR': 1.2296544, 'GBP': 1.5550989,
         'HKD': 0.1270207, 'INR': 0.0177643, 'JPY': 0.01241401,
         'MXN': 0.0751848, 'MYR': 0.3145411, 'NOK': 0.1677063, 
         'NZD': 0.8003591, 'PHP': 0.0233234, 'SEK': 0.148269,  
         'SGD': 0.788871,  'THB': 0.0313789}
 
def curconv(curr, amount):
    if curr not in RATES:
        raise ValueError(f"Unknown Currency Code '{curr}'")* amount
    return RATES[curr] * amount
```

Comment: Perhaps also add the usual sermon about float inaccuracy; probably truncate the result of the conversion to two decimals, or switch to integers units. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, but I don't really see reason for either here. In particular, different currencies may have different number of decimal places, so truncating to two decimals does not seem useful IMHO.